# Как ВКонтакте правильно проверить, что участники сообщества друзья?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу построить граф, который будет связывать участников сообщества, которые находятся друг у друга в друзьях.

Собрала членов сообщества ВКонтакте. Далее хотела получить таблицу, в которой source и target будут участники сообщества, которые являются друзьями.

Как проверяла, что участники друзья и вот так: ошибка токена, хотя его указывала

> {'error': {'error_code': 28, 'error_msg': 'Application authorization failed: method is unavailable with service token.', 'request_params': [{'key': 'v', 'value': '5.131'}, {'key': 'offset', 'value': '0'}, {'key': 'fields', 'value': 'user_ids'}, {'key': 'friend_status', 'value': '3'}, {'key': 'method', 'value': 'friends.areFriends'}, {'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'}]}}

и указывала разрешённые параметры https://vk.com/dev/friends.areFriends

```
for user_id in hall_of_fame.items():
  def are_friends():
    fri = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.areFriends', params={
            'access_token':token,
            'v':5.131,
            'sort':'id_desc',
            'offset': 0,
            'fields':'user_ids',
            'friend_status': 3,
        }).json()
    print(fri)
```

Как получить такую таблицу, в который будет два столбца с айди участников, которые друзья?

Comment: _но при прохождении по каждому участнику сообщества методом friends.get не получается_ А что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @mironovmeow, ошибка по времени запроса - то есть, я проходилась по каждому полученному участнику сообщества, искала его друзей и смотрела, есть ли эти люди среди остальных участников сообщества.

Comment: Ну, тогда, можете показать, как вы искали друзей, где и какая была ошибка? Дополните вопрос, сейчас не до конца понятно, чего вы хотите получить

Comment: @mironovmeow, обновила код получения участников сообщества и написала, как примерно проверяла, что участники друзья. Сейчас объясню, что хочу получить: я хочу построить граф, который соединяет участников сообщества, которые находится друг у друга в друзьях. Получается, с точки зрения запроса вк апи нужно получить таблицу, в которой source и target будут участники сообщества, которые друзья.

Comment: Давайте все же конкретнее, что именно не получается, какая ошибка, у какого кода, на какой строке?

Comment: @Kromster, добавила ещё одну попытку проверить на дружбу пользователей и ошибку

Comment: Вот, а теперь убирайте все лишнее из вопроса и оставляйте только то в чем именно у вас ошибка - "дергаю АПИ ВК вот таким кодом, получаю вот такую ошибку - как исправить?")

Comment: Отредактировала)

Comment: Замечательно, теперь понятно, в чём проблема и сейчас вам отвечу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете [cервисный ключ доступа](https://dev.vk.com/api/access-token/getting-started#%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0), а этот метод работает только с [ключом доступа пользователя](https://dev.vk.com/api/access-token/getting-started#%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F). Об этом говорит ошибка.

Такое чувство, что вы хотите использовать метод [friends.get](https://dev.vk.com/method/friends.get), который возвращает список всех друзей одного пользователя. А вот [метод](https://dev.vk.com/method/friends.areFriends), который вы используете, *возвращает информацию о том, добавлен ли текущий пользователь в друзья у указанных пользователей.*

Предложение для решения вашей задачи: Получить id друзей пользователя: `friends.get` и, среди этих друзей, находить подписчиков группы [`groups.isMember`](https://dev.vk.com/method/groups.isMember).

Comment: Про ключи доступа поняла, спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, а зачем собирать всех друзей всех участников сообщества и по этим данным строить граф, если я хочу построить не просто граф друзей участников сообщества, а выявить друзей среди этих участников? Почему нельзя использовать этот [метод](https://dev.vk.com/method/friends.areFriends)

Comment: Этот метод работает только для токена пользователя, для которого мы и хотим узнать. Хочу уточнить, вы хотите у конкретного пользователя узнать, какие друзья являются участниками группы, верны?

Comment: Именно так. Я подумала, что этот метод будет эффективнее, чем извлекать всех друзей всех участников сообщества (их около 5000) и потом проверять каждого человека из этого огромного списка на членство в сообществе.

Comment: Видимо, вам нужен [`groups.isMember`](https://dev.vk.com/method/groups.isMember). Я обновил ответ с учётом ваших комментариев.

Comment: Пока собираю друзей участников. Приходит много ответов с ошибками (например, ошибка доступа). Не подскажете, как удалить любые возвращённые с ошибкой записи? {'response': {'count': 182, 'items': [{'id':

Comment: {'response': {'count': 182, 'items': [{'id':      {'error': {'error_code': 30, 'error_msg': 'This profile is private',  Чтобы всё, что error, не отображалось в ответе. Наверное, это лучше будет в отдельный вопрос поместить.